# What is the difference between cookie attribute";path=/app" vs ";path=/app/"

Tags: html, cookies, owasp, black-box-testing

ex: www.mysite.com/app/
If the cookie attribute path is set to ";path=/app" will it make any difference to change to ";path=/app/" ?

Comment: The difference is that the first one is a typo.

Comment: I was not talking about the typo, but thank you for response. Could you please let me know what if there is any difference ?

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_cookies_attributes_(OTG-SESS-002)